# How do I click a drop down menu in python using pywinauto?

Tags: python, automation, pyautogui, pywinauto

I have a year's worth of hourly data of steam produced from 3 different boilers, each hour is saved in a separate .dds file. I am trying to create a python (3.10) program to automate opening each .dds file using a specific Data Acquisition Viewer and convert them to excel. The DAQ viewer is old and the only way to access the data from these image files is by opening them in it and then converting to excel.

[DAQ interface w/ convert button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fsy3Z.png)

I am using pywinauto, and the loop in my script works up until the point where I need it to click on the "convert" drop-down menu. All the other automated GUI controls worked because I've used keyboard commands, however there is no way for me to TAB+ENTER to the "convert" menu.

Two reasons I think the code I've tried may not be working:

1. The DAQ viewer is old and incompatible with some pywinauto functions
2. The files open as a separate window when opened in the viewer which could be causing issue with "child window"

The following code is what's working, and goes as far as opening the first file in the DAQ Viewer:

```
import os
import time
import pywinauto
from pywinauto import timings

directory = "C:/python-test/Boiler2"
viewer_exe = "C:/python-test/DAQSTANDARD Viewer/DxViewerE.exe"
app = pywinauto.Application(backend='win32')
app.start(viewer_exe)
main_window = app.window(title='Data Viewer')
time.sleep(0.5)

for filename in os.listdir(directory):
if filename.endswith(".dds"):
dds_file = os.path.join(directory, filename)

    main_window.type_keys('^o')
    time.sleep(0.5)
    open_dialog = app.window(title="Open")
    time.sleep(0.5)
    open_dialog.type_keys("{TAB}{TAB}{TAB}")
    time.sleep(0.5)
    open_dialog.type_keys("{DOWN}")
    time.sleep(0.5)
    open_dialog.type_keys("{ENTER}")
    time.sleep(0.5)
    open_dialog.type_keys("{TAB}")
    time.sleep(0.5)
    open_dialog.type_keys(filename)
    time.sleep(0.5)
    open_dialog.type_keys("{ENTER}")
    time.sleep(0.5)
```

From here I want it to click the convert button shown in attached pictured. The following code is what I've tried:

```
main_window.click(title='Convert', control_type='Button')
time.sleep(0.2)
main_window.click(title='To Excel', control_type='Button')
time.sleep(0.2)
export_dialog = app.window(title='Convert', lvisible=True)
time.sleep(0.2)
export_dialog.click(title='Ok', control_type='Button')
main_window.menu_select("File -> Close")
```

I get the following error:

```
line 43: main_window.click(title='Convert', control_type='Button') 
TypeError: HwndWrapper.click() got an unexpected keyword argument 'title'
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a wrong usage of method `click()`. First you need to create window specification (analogue of Locator in Selenium):

```
btn = main_window.child_window(title='Convert', control_type='Button')
```

then you can find it actually and call `.click()` method:

```
btn.wrapper_object().click()
```

or just

```
btn.click()
```

which finds the wrapper automatically and calls `.click()` method. If search is failed (no element with such search criteria), it should raise `ElementNotFoundError` exception with details at which level search is failed.

P.S. Hard-coded `time.sleep`s is not a good practice. I'd recommend using these methods where possible: https://pywinauto.readthedocs.io/en/latest/wait_long_operations.html